# How to get value by column name and datatype?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
for (int i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(selectStatement); i++)                 
    {
        int intValue = 0;
        const char *strValue;
        switch (sqlite3_column_type(selectStatement,i)) 
        {
        }
}
```

I'm iterating columns and comparing the type. How can I get the value by specifying datatype and column name to create a dynamic query system? Android equivalent where I have the cursor object globally :

```
public Object get(String name, QueryDbType type) throws Exception {
        Object retult = null;
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(name);
        switch (type) {
        case Text:
            retult = cursor.getString(index);
            break;
        case Int:
            retult = cursor.getInt(index);
            break;
        
        default:
            retult = cursor.getString(index);
            break;
        }
        return retult;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is; you know which column is which in the result as you can specify the columns to fetch in the `SELECT` statement and you know what the datatype is as it's part of the schema.  Unless you are creating some sort of dynamic query system?

Comment: @trojanfoe - Yes its for dynamic query system

Comment: OK so are you using `SELECT * FROM` or `SELECT name, name, name FROM`?

Comment: Only i need to execute. I will get the query, column name and column datatype. I need to send all the result values of those. I will get only SELECT * FROM. The same functionality we can achieve in android sqlite. So i am asking is the same we can achieve in ios too.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Updated my question please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get the column name -> index mapping. You will have to do it manually. If you have lot of fields, you could build a map/dictionary as follows:

```objectivec
for (int i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(selectStatement); i++) {
    name = sqlite3_column_name(selectStatement, i);
    // add name to the dictionary 
    dict[name] = i;
}
```

You can then query the dictionary by name to get the column index. Using the column index you can get the value.

If you don't have a lot of fields, you could just loop and find the index also.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the [sqlite3_column_*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) function for the datatype that you want; SQLite will automatically convert the column value to that type, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I dont know the column index also. Will this work for the same?